# How to connect component from external package with react-redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

My app use my own NPM package, grouping some components.

I define this in the main index.ts of my app:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

App component declare the Router. Each route is either use internal component or external component from my NPM package.

The connect function of react-redux works fine with internal components.
However, I have an error when I try to use connect with external components :

> Could not find "store" in the context of "Connect(ExternalComponent)".
>   Either wrap the root component in a `<Provider>`, or pass a custom React
>   context provider to `<Provider>` and the corresponding React context
>   consumer to Connect(ExternalComponent) in connect options.

I can understand the issue : what a mess to share the state of an app with any external component in any package using connect for internal needs...

However, is there a way to handle it for my case ?

I can't think it's so an unusual situation. 
Of course, I tried to Google it, but I'm a beginner in React/Redux world, so maybe I haven't find the right words for this.

**Edit 1**

This is how I define my store variable.

```
import reducer from 'myNpmPackage/src/reducers';
import middleware from 'myNpmPackage/src/middleware';
const store = createStore(reducer, middleware);
```

As you can see, reducers and middlewares are parts of my NPM package.

**Edit 2**

This is my ExternalComponent :

```
import React, { PureComponent, Fragment } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

interface IExternalComponentProps {}

interface IExternalComponentState {}

class ExternalComponent extends PureComponent<IExternalComponentProps, IExternalComponentState>{

    public render() {
         return (
            <div className="ExternalComponent">
                External !
            </div>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps ({ test }: any) {
  return {
    test
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ExternalComponent);
```

This is my App component declaring the Router :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route
} from 'react-router-dom';

import ExternalComponent from 'myNpmPackage/src/components/external-component/ExternalComponent.js';
// import InternalComponent from './components/internal-component/InternalComponent';

interface IAppProps {}

interface IAppState {}

class App extends React.Component<IAppProps, IAppState> {

    public render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <div className="component-container">
                    <Router>
                       <div>
                           <Route exact path='/' component={ExternalComponent} />
                      </div>
                   </Router>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default connect()(App);
```

As you can see, ExternalComponent is use through JS format, after TypeScript compilation.

Comment: Please add your store code here.

Comment: yes, it's untypical case. can you add code snippet how do you wrap component with `connect()`?

Comment: and provide also part where you integrate that with `<Route>`

Comment: I found the issue : I was working with a symlink via the npm link command. 
Without it, it's fine. But symlink is very very useful during the dev... :( Anyone ?

Comment: hm, now it sounds like completely different question. I believe it makes sense to create new one. anyway you need to provide webpack config since there are special config options related [to path resolving](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve-symlinks) and describe folders structure and where are symlinks

Comment: I use Create React App, so I think I can't provide anything to Webpack config, right ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, I posted an issue on CRA's Github :
https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/6027

A team had the same issue, they found the solution. Just for the record, I report it here :

> Change the resolve.modules inside webpack.config.js from
>   this:
>
> modules: ['node_modules'].concat(/* ... */), to this:
>
> modules: [path.resolve('node_modules'), 'node_modules'].concat(/* ...
>   */),

Moreover, they made a PR, you can find it here : 
https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/6207

Thanks to them !